# each() function. Can someone advise me how to shorten this code

Tags: jquery

The code I have below works fine but I'm sure it could be more streamlined.

The script basically resizes an image and positions it horizontally in the centre of its containing div no matter the screen size.

The two functions within function "resizeBg" are identical apart from the fact that they point at different divs (".block1" and ".block2") containing an image with a different class (".bg1" and ".bg2").

I need the function resizeBG to be applied separately to each div. One image could be portrait while the other could be landscape so the outcome is different depending on the image proportions. This is the only way I can get this to work just now but I realise it could be so much simpler/neater.

HTML

```
<div class="block block1">
    IMAGE
</div>
<div class="block block2">
    IMAGE
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block1 {background: #000000;}
.block2 {background: ffffff;}

.block {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

.bgwidth { 
  width: 100%;
  }

.bgheight { 
  height: 100%;
  }
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
// FULLSCREEN BACKGROUND IMAGE
var theWindow = $(window);
var block1 = $('.block1');
bg1 = block1.children(".bg1");
var block2 = $('.block2');
bg2 = block2.children(".bg2");
aspectRatio1 = bg1.width() / bg1.height();
aspectRatio2 = bg2.width() / bg2.height();

function resizeBg() {

    $('.block1').each(function() {
        if ((block1.width() / block1.height()) < aspectRatio1) {
            bg1.removeClass('bgwidth').addClass('bgheight');
            if(bg1.width() > block1.width()) {
                bg1.each(function(){
                    //get width (unitless) and divide by 2
                    var hWide = ($(this).width() - block1.width())/2;
                    // attach negative and pixel for CSS rule
                    hWide = '-' + hWide + 'px';
                    $(this).addClass("js-fix").css({
                        "margin-left" : hWide
                        });
                    });
                }
            else {
                bg1.each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("js-fix").css({
                        "margin-left" : 0 + 'px'
                        });
                    });
                };
        } else {
            bg1.removeClass('bgheight').addClass('bgwidth');

            bg1.each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("js-fix").css({
                    "margin-left" : 0 + 'px'
                });
            });
        }

    });




    $('.block2').each(function() {
        if ((block2.width() / block2.height()) < aspectRatio2) {
            bg2.removeClass('bgwidth').addClass('bgheight');
            if(bg2.width() > block2.width()) {
                bg2.each(function(){
                    //get width (unitless) and divide by 2
                    var hWide = ($(this).width() - block2.width())/2;
                    // attach negative and pixel for CSS rule
                    hWide = '-' + hWide + 'px';
                    $(this).addClass("js-fix").css({
                        "margin-left" : hWide
                        });
                    });
                }
            else {
                bg2.each(function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("js-fix").css({
                        "margin-left" : 0 + 'px'
                        });
                    });
                };
        } else {
            bg2.removeClass('bgheight').addClass('bgwidth');

            bg2.each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("js-fix").css({
                    "margin-left" : 0 + 'px'
                });
            });
        }

    });


}

theWindow.resize(function () {
    resizeBg();
}).trigger("resize");
```

});

Comment: well you can use CSS to do the centering part, which then means you only need jQuery to resize the image.

Do you have a live demo we can see and work from?

Comment: Instead of defining `bg1` and `bg2` beforehand, you can simply call `$(this).children()` inside the callback. Then you can use the same code for both element types.

Comment: Also, take a look below to see how you can refactor the loops where you have $(this).removeClass("js-fix").css({"margin-left" : 0 + 'px'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I [gave it a shot](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/muUU5/). Basically you just need to refactor your code so that it is more generic and can work on each element in your jQuery object. I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, I didn't really pay attention too much to what was going on in the code, I just genericized it so that you don't have to write the same code twice. It may be able to be refactored further, this is just to give you an idea as to what you should be doing.

Comment: I'll give this a little go Jason. Might take me a minute or two. I'm still pretty new to jquery. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are an absolute star, thanks so much it worked a treat! I tried to give you a vote up but this is my first post.

I'm going to go and read through your code now so that I understand it. Thanks again.

Comment: no worries! glad it worked for you :) i don't know your programming background, but assuming you're new, you should always code in the most generic way possible so that you you [don't have to repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). Good luck!

Comment: Yeah totally, I could tell it wasn't right because I was repeating a lot of code. I just didn't quite have the smarts to get it going.I'll read that wiki link now.

Comment: You can see an example of it working properly here guys.  http://jsfiddle.net/sambadave/BxsUc/2/ Thanks again Jason. And thanks everyone else who has offered guidance.

Comment: great answer. Upvoted...
Can I just ask what is the `^=` in `'[class^=bg]'`?
 I've not seen that operator used before.
Is it different from doing `.children('.bg')`?

Comment: @DigitalBiscuits because he had classes `.bg1` and `.bg2` i decided to use a ["starts with" operator](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to select the child that starts with "bg"

Comment: Yeah I was wondering that myself. So I take it "ends with" would be =^ yeah?

Comment: @sambadave ends with is `$=`.. if you know regex, you'd get the connection

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.block').each(function() {
    var $block = $(this), 
    blockWidth = $block.width(),
    blockHeight = $block.height(),
    blockRatio = blockWidth / blockHeight,
    className = $block.attr('class'),
    $bg = $('.bg' + className.substr(className.length-1)),
    bgWidth = $bg.width(),
    bgHeight = $bg.height(),
    bgRatio = bgWidth / bgHeight;

    if (blockRatio < bgRatio) {
        $bg.removeClass('bgwidth').addClass('bgheight');
        if(bgWidth > blockWidth) {
            $bg.addClass('js-fix')
            .css('margin-left',
            '-' + ((bgWidth - blockWidth)/2) + 'px';
        } else {
            $bg.removeClass('js-fix').css('margin-left','0');
        }
    } else {
        $bg.removeClass('bgheight').addClass('bgwidth')
        .removeClass('js-fix').css('margin-left','0');
    }
});
```

FYI: 0px === 0pt === 0em === 0